# c# - How to convert a converted UTF8 string to UTF16?

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8, utf-16, string-conversion

I'm trying to convert a converted UTF-8 string to UTF-16, because I'm going to read a file and it comes like the var `strUTF8` below.

For example, the entry would be the string `"NÃ£o Ã© possÃ­vel equipar"` and the return I needed is `"Não é possível equipar"`.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    test3();
    Console.ReadKey();
}

static void test3()
{
    string str = "NÃ£o Ã© possÃ­vel equipar";
    string strUTF16 = Utf8ToUtf16(str);

    Console.WriteLine(str);
    Console.WriteLine(strUTF16);
}

static string Utf8ToUtf16(string utf8String)
{
    byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(utf8String);
    byte[] unicodeBytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Unicode, utf8Bytes);
    return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(unicodeBytes);
}
```

I really don't know how to solve this. Any tips?

Comment: Specify the encoding at the source. If you receive a mangled string you can’t reliably correct it later as not all byte sequences can be mapped without loss to UTF-8 or other encodings.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read a file then you should read a file. When you read the file, specify the encoding of that file. If I'm not mistaken UTF8 is the default, so reading files encoded with UTF8 doesn't require the encoding to be specified. If you want to save that text to a file with a specific encoding, specify that encoding when saving the file.

```cs
var text = File.ReadAllText(filePath, Encoding.UTF8);

File.WriteAllText(filePath, text, Encoding.Unicode);
```

That will effectively convert a file from UTF8 encoding to UTF16. A more verbose version would be:

```cs
var data = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
var text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);

data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text);
File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, data);
```

Comment: It's `UTF8`, not `Utf8`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Utf8ToUtf16()` function is effectively a **no-op**.  You are taking an arbitrary UTF-16 string as input, encoding it into UTF-8 bytes, then decoding those bytes as UTF-8 back into UTF-16.  So, you effectively end up with the same `string` value you started with.  You may as well have just written the following, the result would be the same:

```cs
static string Utf8ToUtf16(string utf8String)
{
    return utf8String;
}
```

That being said, `NÃ£o Ã© possÃ­vel equipar` is what you get when the UTF-8 encoded form of `Não é possível equipar` is *mis*-interpreted as Latin (probably ISO-8859-1) or Windows-125x etc, instead of being *properly* interpreted as UTF-8 to begin with.

If you have a C# `string` that contains such UTF-8 bytes which were up-scaled as-is to UTF-16 (why???), then you need to down-scale those characters as-is back into 8-bit bytes, and then you can decode those bytes as UTF-8, eg:

```
static void test3()
{
    string str = "NÃ£o Ã© possÃ­vel equipar";
    string strUTF16 = Utf8ToUtf16(str);

    Console.WriteLine(str);
    Console.WriteLine(strUTF16);
}

static string Utf8ToUtf16(string utf8String)
{
    byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(utf8String); // or: GetEncoding(28591)
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8Bytes);
}
```